# Element type with 'baked-in' fields

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I've created an element type and want to have a 'Categories' and 'Tags' field built-in (the sources for each will be selectable in settings), but can't figure out the best way to go about this whilst supporting custom field layouts with tabs.

Do I just hard-code these fields into the edit page/hud html code then handle the logic on the save controller (this is fiddly whilst keeping it customisable/tab-able), or is there a better way to do it? I.e inject them into the field layout via the controller?

Can't get my head around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given up on this, from what I've looked at it's not going to be easy without a migration that creates the fields first (don't really want to do this for updatability issues). I've changed the scope of the plugin to be more bare-bones, and I think it's better for it.